# xlsx get_worksheet_by_name return none?

Tags: python, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have my code like this :

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('result.xlsx')

sheet = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name('result')
```

but sheet always be None
I have checked my result.xlsx.I'm sure result.xlsx have 'result' sheet.
Why?

Answer (score 4):

xlsxwriter, as the name suggests, can't read xlsx files but only write them. By doing this `xlsxwriter.Workbook('result.xlsx')` you create a new python object, but you're not actually reading or writing that file on your hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

As Joost answered, xlsxwriter can't read xlsx files but only write them. Maybe you could use codes below to instead:

```
data = openpyxl.load_workbook('result.xlsx')
sheet = data['result']
```